# how to test promise returning functions

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, mocha.js, chai

I have following async function that return Promise.

```
static getAccessToken(env: DeploymentEnv, username: string, password: string): Promise<AccessToken>;
```

Now, this the unit test that I wrote for it.

```
it("should be able to get access token",async ()=>{
    let accessToken = await IModelHubServiceBusClient.getAccessToken('QA',
                      'abc@xyz.com',
                      'abc')!;

    assert.exists(accessToken);
});
```

When run it, it fails the test saying the following error:

```
should be able to get access token:
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

What Am I doing wrong, any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us implementation of `getAccessToken` or ensure that it's always resolve/reject

Comment: `static getAccessToken(env, username, password) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
                let auth = yield new ImsClients_1.ImsActiveSecureTokenClient(env).getToken(username, password);
let atoken = yield new ImsClients_1.ImsDelegationSecureTokenClient(env).getToken(auth);
 if (atoken) {
             resolve(atoken);
            }
                reject("Failed to get token");
            }));
           return promise;
        });
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `done` callback if you test async code

```
it("should be able to get access token",async (done)=>{
    let accessToken = await IModelHubServiceBusClient.getAccessToken('QA',
                      'bistroDEV_pmadm1@mailinator.com',
                      'pmadm1')!;

    assert.exists(accessToken);
    done();
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and returning the same error. Any more suggestions? The error is: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: I tried adding a console in it like this: `it("should be able to get access token",async (done)=>{
        let accessToken = await IModelHubServiceBusClient.getAccessToken('QA',
                          'bistroDEV_pmadm1@mailinator.com',
                          'pmadm1')!;
        console.log(accessToken);
        //assert.exists(accessToken);
        done();
    }); `Now it still throws the same exception but after few seconds, it outputs the accessToken's value as well.

Comment: This is definitely not needed with recent mocha versions